# Comparator with container of pairs with pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, templates

The following codes gives the correct output except for the line that is commented out, which won't compile (update:  fixed).  I was wondering if there was a generic way to define the function `lessBySecondPointer` by using `lessBySecond` without redefining.   Though trivial here, what if it was much more complex?  Is there a generic way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <type_traits>
#include <set>

template <typename T, typename U, typename F = std::less<U>>  // F allows for using other comparators than <.
bool lessBySecond (const std::pair<T, U>& a, const std::pair<T, U>& b) {
    return F()(a.second, b.second);
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename F = std::less<typename std::decay<decltype(*U())>::type>>
bool lessBySecondPointer (const std::pair<T, U>& a, const std::pair<T, U>& b) {
   return F()(*a.second, *b.second);  // How to use 'lessBySecond' instead of redefining?
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename F = std::less<typename std::decay<decltype(*U())>::type>>
struct LessBySecondPointer {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<T, U>& a, const std::pair<T, U>& b) const {
        return lessBySecondPointer<T, U, F>(a, b);
    }
};

struct Thing {
    int value;
    friend bool operator < (const Thing& a, const Thing& b) { return a.value < b.value; }
    friend bool operator > (const Thing& a, const Thing& b) { return b < a; }
};

int main() {
    std::list<std::pair<char, Thing>> list = { {'a', {4}}, {'b', {3}}, {'c', {5}} };
    list.sort(lessBySecond<char, Thing>);
    for (const auto& pair : list) std::cout << pair.second.value << ' ';  // 3 4 5
    std::cout << "\n\nNow with std::list<std::pair<char, Thing*>>:\n";
    std::pair<char, Thing*> x{'a', new Thing{4}}, y{'b', new Thing{3}}, z{'c', new Thing{5}};
    bool t = lessBySecondPointer<char, Thing*>(x,y);  // Compiles fine.
    std::cout << t << '\n';  // Shows false, as it is supposed to.
    std::list<std::pair<char, Thing*>> pointerList = { x, y, z };
    pointerList.sort(lessBySecondPointer<char, Thing*>);  // Works fine now
    std::set<std::pair<char, Thing*>, LessBySecondPointer<char, Thing*>> set = { x, y, z };
    for (const auto& pair : set) std::cout << pair.second->value << ' ';   // 3 4 5
}
```

Comment: The compilation error is obvious. You declared `list` as a `std::list<std::pair<char, Thing>>` at the beginning of your program. Time and wishes doesn't change that. So a comparator expecting `pair<char,Thing*>` instead of `pair<char,Thins>` is wrong for that container type. You used the correct comparator prior (second line of program). Maybe I'm just not seeing what the real goal is here.

Comment: Darn.  Forgot to change the name.  Done now.  Ok, what about my second question?  How to define the function lessBySecondPointer by using lessBySecond without redefining.

Comment: Since they take two fundamentally different types, I don't see how to do it easily with without reconstruction of some sort. You can only invoke `lessBySecond` with specific pair types, and fundamentally different pair types are what you have.